# I purchased a mountain bike back in the 1990's at a yard sale

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: this is opposite side of mtb. Focused in on chain rings ... The only items that are not oem are: the center pull brakes, the brake levers, the seat, and the handlebar extensions]No markings. 2" crossbar & 2" downtube.  Rims are stamped "Peninsula Italy".  Looks like a 21 speed.  26" bicycle. Been stored for awhile ... dusting off for exercise (jogging is out). Wondering who made this mountain bike.  (Would like to add appropriate decals.)  There is a number stamped on the frame at the base of the down tube ... 728027. Any help would be appreciated.  Derailleur-rear is marked "Shimano 7SIS.  More pics available....

[image: this is opposite side of mtb. Focused in on chain rings ... The only items that are not oem are: the center pull brakes, the brake levers, the seat, and the handlebar extensions]

Parts of the mtb that are NOT original are: brake levers, center pull front & rear brakes, (mtb came with old cantilever brakes), flat bar extensions, seat, lights front & rear, and both tires.

Comment: The brand of the rear derailleur isn't going to help you much: there are three main brands (Shimano, SRAM and Campagnolo) that cover almost every derailleur on the planet, and Shimano seem to have the lower-end market completely sewn up. Likewise, the wheels were probably bought as components so are unlikely to tell you much about the bike.

Comment: Suggest new brake pads (They harden with age) and tires are probably past it as well. I guess low end bike - oversized tubes did not come in till mid 1990's, by which time shocks and 8speed were standard on any reasonable bike.

Comment: Note that the bike appears to have V-brakes, and the modern V-brake was introduced by Shimano in 1996.

Comment: Fixed tags. Identify this bike is the best category.

Comment: I've rolled this back because your last edit lost all of the question.  SE is about building the best set of answers to your question, so while you can totally edit it and refine the question, don't take out significant details or fundamentally change the question.

Comment: I apologise for removing information ... that was not my intension.  I was having trouble adding caption to the last picture I posted.  Turned out to be network garbage interference.  What I wanted to add was that the parts of the mtb that are NOT orginal are:  brake levers,  center pull front & rear brakes, (mtb came with old cantilever brakes), flat bar extensions,  seat,  lights front & rear, tires front & rear.  I also am looking for an app that I can view different paint schemes on a mtg frame.  Any help would be great.  Thank You.

Comment: Thank You Criggie for the tips ... have started checking out the glossary.

Answer (score 5):

From the look of the frame and components, I'd say it could be any OEM/No-name supermarket bicycle.

Comment: I was thinking the same. ... a friend that cycles said I should check into maker .. b/c of the rims being Italian made.

Comment: Is that significant?

Comment: Agree with Kenned. The stamping on the wheels is probably just that... a name stamped into the rim. I have not heard of Peninsula Italy as rim maker and Google is not helping either. Rest of the frame looks like it could have originated anywhere and the lack of branding on other parts does not make me believe they are high-end parts.

Comment: I appreciate all the information.  I enjoy riding this mtb b/c its very sturdy and rider friendly.  Thinking about painting.  That was the reason for the post. ..... I wanted to return it to orginal if possible.  But a new paint scheme will be cool also.

Comment: "peninsula italy" probably has no connection with Italy or any peninsula in existence, just like Masi frames claim to be italian even when made in the US.

Comment: It's not your cheapest BSO, since it has a 3-piece crank.  It's a step or two above that.

Comment: Pls excuse my ignorance. What does BSO mean?

Comment: @M.Taylor [Its in the glossary](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/887/19705)  and stands for Bicycle Shaped Object.

Comment: To Daniel R Hicks:  I am very interested in your opinion ... can you talk more about what information I can provide (pic or txt) to aid in some further identification of this mtb.

Comment: ÀDaniel R Hicks I am very interested in your opinion ... can you talk more about what information I can provide (pic or txt) to aid in some further identification of this mtb

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a generic rigid MTB, with V brakes and a "comfort" shaped saddle.

Not sure why there is paper in the spokes - possible covering reflector to help the camera take a better photo?

Generally speaking we're interested in the other side of the bike because it has the transmission (chain and gears etc)

The bike looks decent, and I would ride it if it fit me.  So ride it like you want to.  If you're just riding on road, when the tyres wear out or crack then get replacements with fewer or no knobs, and you'll go faster for less effort.

If you want to paint it then do so - paint it a colour you like and want to see.  Just do the hard prep work to make it a good paint job, not a bodgy rattlecan effort.

Comment: Pls excuse my ignorance.  What does BSO mean?

Comment: @M.Taylor [Its in the glossary](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/887/19705)  and stands for Bicycle Shaped Object.